# How To Merge Two Sections Together In HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to merge two sections together from my website.I highlighted them in a red box.
[image: personal webpage, showing that the sections described are indeed not merged and there's some space separating them]
as you can see above, the image shows clearly that the sections are separated by some space

```css
#ABC {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0%;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: zero;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: lightblue
}

nav {
  padding: 5px;
  color: mediumpurple;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(lightgray, wheat);
}

#Introduction {
  background-image: linear-gradient(wheat, white);
  padding: 0%;
}

#Numbers {
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, lime);
  padding: 0%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a target="" href="cats/Menu.html"><i>Visit page 2</i></a>
    <a target="" href="pagina3.html"><i>Visit page 3</i></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com"><i>Youtube's home page</i></a>
  </nav>
  <h1>
    <a target="" href="index.html">
      <img src="plant.png" height="50"></a> Vlad Seboiu</h1>
  <hr/>
</header>
<main>
  <article>
    <section id="Introduction">
      <p>
        <h2 id="ABC"><big>Introduction</big></h2>
      </p>
      <p>hello world</p>
    </section>
    <section id="Numbers">
      <p>10000<sup>2</sup></p>
      <p> H<sub>2</sub>O</p>
      <p>(-20)<sup>52</sup>(-40)<sup>95</sup></p>
    </section>
  </article>
</main>
<footer style="background-color:white">
  <!-- 
               test 
             -->
  <hr/>
  <h2>test</h2>
  <p style="color:green;background-color:chartreuse;">
    <big>
                    123
                </big>
  </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: You should learn how to use your browser's document inspector to examine the page elements. This kind of thing is trivial to find. Also, you should not have a heading element inside a paragraph element. Please look into semantic document structure. You also shouldn't use inline styles. They clutter your markup and make your work more difficult.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the feedback! I'm a beginner and anything helps!

Answer (score 1):

The margin on your paragraphs is separating the two sections. You can view this is the case by opening dev tools with <kbd>F12</kbd> and inspecting them. The coloured box that pops up shows your margins. A quick fix could be to add a class to the paragraphs in question:

```css
.clear-margin {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
#ABC {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0%;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: zero;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: lightblue
}

nav {
  padding: 5px;
  color: mediumpurple;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(lightgray, wheat);
}

.clear-margin {
  margin: 0;
}

#Introduction {
  background-image: linear-gradient(wheat, white);
  padding: 0%;
}

#Numbers {
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, lime);
  padding: 0%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a target="" href="cats/Menu.html"><i>Visit page 2</i></a>
    <a target="" href="pagina3.html"><i>Visit page 3</i></a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com"><i>Youtube's home page</i></a>
  </nav>
  <h1>
    <a target="" href="index.html">
      <img src="plant.png" height="50"></a> Vlad Seboiu</h1>
  <hr/>
</header>
<main>
  <article>
    <section id="Introduction">
      <p>
        <h2 id="ABC"><big>Introduction</big></h2>
      </p>
      <p class="clear-margin">hello world</p>
    </section>
    <section id="Numbers">
      <p class="clear-margin">10000<sup>2</sup></p>
      <p> H<sub>2</sub>O</p>
      <p>(-20)<sup>52</sup>(-40)<sup>95</sup></p>
    </section>
  </article>
</main>
<footer style="background-color:white">
  <!-- 
               test 
             -->
  <hr/>
  <h2>test</h2>
  <p style="color:green;background-color:chartreuse;">
    <big>
                    123
                </big>
  </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: @isherwood Apologies for my carelessness. Here is an improved answer for you

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` has default margin.
Add this to your css

```
p{
    margin:0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

p tag has margin which is not merging two section

just do this:

```
 p {margin:0px;}
```

https://codepen.io/Aksshit/pen/dyqMWzd
check this for solution which I tried on codepen.

Tip: Always use Developer Tools to first know the problem.